# I want to do a POST request in POSTMAN with xml in body but I get some errors

Tags: xml, postman

I want to do a Post request in Postman with an xml as body but I get an error and I don`t know much about xml.

This is my xml

```
<header xmlns=\"xxx:v1"
                    xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
    <upload fisier=\"JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMTAgMCBvYmoKPDwvRiAxMzIvVHlwZS9Bbm5vdC9TdWJ0eXBl
                    L1dpZGdldC9SZWN0WzUwMCA2NzUgNjAwIDc3NV0vRlQvU2lnL0RSPDwvWE9iamVjdDw8
                    L0ZSTSA4IDAgUj4+Pj4vVChTaWduYXR1cmUxKS9WIDEgMCBSL1AgMTEgMCBSL0FQPDwv
                    TiA5IDAgUj4+Pj4KZW5kb2JqCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwvQ29udGVudHMgPDA0ODIwMTAwYjJl
                    L1NpemUgNTA+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKMTM0MTcKJSVFT0YK\"/>
</header>
```

On line number 2 and four I have an error that says : A.attribute xmlns missed start quot(")!!
B.attribut space is acequired"xmlns"!!
C.element parse error: Error: attribute value must after "="

What do I have to modify in my xml to make the Post work in Postman ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a valid XML file. Try something like that to make sure:
https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/935507)

Comment: @davidbaumann the site is a validator tool. While the answer is light on advice, the target site makes this not really a Link-only answer.